# Unable to use Intel AES-NI sample library to encrypt/decrypt in 32-byte block size

Tags: c++, encryption, aes, intel, aes-ni

I am trying to use the intel_aes_c library with C++ on Visual Studio to create an encryption method that encrypts in 32-byte block sizes, but even when doing a #define BLOCK_SIZE (32) does not really help.

In general, I would like to ask how I can set block sizes in the Intel AES-NI Sample Library. Any help or clarification to point me in the right way would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: How do you know this will work? The official documentation states: "The AES algorithm works by encrypting a fixed block size of 128 bits of plain text in several rounds to produce the final encrypted cipher text."

Comment: Thanks for your reply Floris. I am terribly sorry, because I did not notice that! Could you refer me to where that is? Although I have somewhat noticed that the source code does not have any variables to edit the block size, b would want to confirm with someone else out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am aware the block size of plain text cannot be changed (if you are to encrypt it) with AES-NI. This is specified by Intel:

> **The AES algorithm works by encrypting a fixed block size of 128 bits of plain text in several rounds to produce the final encrypted cipher text**. The number of rounds (10, 12, or 14) used depends on the key length (128b, 192b, or 256b). Each round performs a sequence of steps on the input state, which is then fed into the following round. Each round is encrypted using a subkey that is generated using a key schedule. For more details on AES please refer to 1. - [Link](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-advanced-encryption-standard-instructions-aes-ni)

The reference mentioned at the end ( 1 ) refers to [a wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) about AES which states:

> AES is a variant of Rijndael which has a **fixed block size of 128 bits**,
>   and a key size of 128, 192, or 256 bits.

Comment: Hello! Apparently I have to read more on it - I was merely dabbling and playing around with it and I thought I can change some simple variables. 

Thanks Floris!